# Trigger on lead Bulikification

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce-id, before-trigger

If industry=='Finance' on the lead then the Lead owner needs to be changed as the account owner(custom lookup field account on Lead-Account__C).I have created the below trigger but not sure if its correctly bulkified and following best practices.

```
trigger LeadOwnerChange on Lead (before update) {
    set<id>accid=new set<id>();
    for(lead lead:trigger.new){
        if(lead.industry=='Finance'){
            accid.add(lead.account__c);
        }
    }
    if(accid.size()>0)
    {
        Map<id,account>accmap=new map<id,account>([select id,ownerid from account where id in:accid]);
        System.debug('accmap>>'+accmap);
        for(lead l:trigger.new){
            if(accmap.containskey (l.account__c)){
                l.ownerid=accmap.get(l.account__c).ownerid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The code is bulkified, but has a few logic errors. In a trigger of more than one lead at a time, if both have the same account, but only one is a finance lead, then both will be assigned to the new owner. Also, if it is a finance lead but has no account, it won't be transferred anyways, so no point in wasting a query. This may be an unexpected surprise if you don't know about it.

Fortunately, both of these are easy to fix. We'll create a temporary list that only contains leads we need to process. This will also slightly trade memory for CPU time when there's only a small number of records to process in a large transaction (it'll run faster than looping over all records twice).

---

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
Lead[] financeLeads = new Lead[0];
for(Lead record: Trigger.new) {
  if(record.Industry == 'Finance' && record.Account__c != null) {
    financeLeads.add(record);
    accounts.put(record.Account__c, null);
  }
}
if(!accounts.isEmpty()) {
  accounts.putAll([SELECT OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id = :accounts.keySet()]);
  for(Lead record: financeLeads) {
    record.OwnerId = accounts.get(record.Account__c).OwnerId;
  }
}
```